# How to wrap FileServer and HTTP api in one specific Handler

Tags: go

I define my own router using for http api and fileSystem. But these two handlers haven't the same type format, how should to combine them in one specific type?

```
type App struct {
    mux      customRouter
    och      *ochttp.Handler
    mw       []Middleware
}

func (a *App) Handle(verb, path string, handler Handler, mw ...Middleware) {

    // First wrap handler specific middleware around this handler.
    handler = wrapMiddleware(mw, handler)

    // The function to execute for each request.
    h := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
    }

    // Add this handler for the specified verb and route.
    a.mux.MethodFunc(verb, path, h)
}

func (a *App) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a.och.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}


// the api handler type format
// type Handler func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error
// the filesystem handler type format
// type Handler func(ctx context.Context, root http.FileSystem) error
// want:
// app.Handle(verb, path, func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)...)
// app.Handle(verb, path, func(ctx context.Context, root http.FileSystem)...)
```

Comment: You can't have two `app.Handle` functions with different signatures, that's called overloading which Go does *not* support. If what you want to do is to wrap a "filesystem Handler" so that it can be passed to app.Handle **as** an "api Handler" then you can do that the same way as already demonstrated in my answer to your previous question, all you would need to change, to make it work for these specific handler types, is the type of the input of the wrapper function and how the closure then invokes the input handler. See this https://play.golang.com/p/VcbECMFm9aC it compiles and it will work.

Comment: One question: how can you response to http in you filesystem handler, cause that handler did not accept http.ResponseWriter as param.

Comment: @mkopriva tks for nice code template, I will dig it deeper and give the result out here.

Comment: @BillyYuan the source code of FileServer return the normal Handler, I think it internal contain the responseWriter yet, so it can be just put http.FileSystem as the only argument.

Comment: responseWriter is passed from http.ServeHttp. when you implement you router, you accept that from ServeHttp and pass to you own handler. You need the original responseWriter to write response. That's why you can't implement one responseWriter internal.

Comment: @BillyYuan not possible with the code example in the my previous comment, which is intended to only demonstrate how to do what OP asked for, that is, if I understood their question correctly. An actual implementation would have to of course provide access to the writer in some way, e.g. some middleware in-between, or the closure itself, could store the writer in the context, or the closure could initialize a custom implementation of `http.FileSystem`, that itself would hold a reference to the writer.

Comment: @BillyYuan .... That way you could keep the minimal signature of the fs Handler. But I would not recommend that over an additional http.ResponseWriter argument to the fs Handler function signature.

Comment: @mkopriva it seems the http.Handler can accept any pattern if it implement the ServeHTTP method, if I change my `type Handler` to `http.Handler`, will it match both the api and filesystem pattern?

Comment: @ccd I'm not sure what you mean by pattern. What pattern? `http.Handler` doesn't accept *any* pattern, through its sole `ServeHTTP` method it *accepts* two arguments of specific type in specific order, namely `http.ResponseWriter` and `*http.Request`, there's nothing else it accepts, no pattern. Let's not confuse terms more than necessary.

Comment: For example, the `http.Handle` will accept fileSystem argument, also it can accept any api like (request, writer) handler, so I think filesystem and api are both considered as  the http.Handler, is it way to get overload for app.Handle?

Comment: @ccd No, `http.Handle` will not accept "fileSystem", whatever you mean by that, whether it's the `http.FileSystem` type, or whether you're talking about your custom "filesystem Handler", `http.Handle` **will not accept** *any* of those. As is evident from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) `http.Handle` will **only** accept a value of type `http.Handler`, this is nonnegiotiable, Go is statically typed language.

Comment: @ccd  It is simply **wrong** to say *"it will accept fileSystem"*, or *"it can accept any api like (request, writer) handler"*, or *"filesystem and api are both considered as the http.Handler"*, all of these are INCORRECT, just try it and let the compiler disprove your assumptions. Let me restate that: your filesystem handler does NOT implement the http.Handler interface, your api handler does NOT implement the http.Handler interface, therefore, neither of them can be used directly as the argument to `http.Handle`, period.

Comment: @ccd is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? I've answer your original question in my first comment, did that not work for you? If that's the case you can update the question and provide details of the issues you've encountered. If, on the other hand, that suggestion worked for you, I am at a complete loss trying to understand what it is that you are asking. What is it that you're after? What are you trying to achieve? If you're just trying to understand how Go works then there's no better source of information than the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: @ccd If, instead, you have specific issues implementing some specific piece of code, then you should include that code in the question, describe the problem, and include any and all errors that the compiler/runtime might have given you. The current question, as it stands, is answered by the first comment accurately, if I may say so myself, however, if you weren't able to use the suggestion from the comment you should update your question explaining what went wrong.

Comment: @mkopriva I try to reformat my previous code, the code template seem a little bit difficult for me to work with. I refresh the source code of net/http, and I find this line `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp")))` in `func FileSystem`, so I make my consider above.

Comment: @mkopriva suppose in my App struct, it contains my 3rd router and a trace library och. The app.Handle wrap all the Handler to middleware, then inject the och context. Last implement the och Handler with ServeHTTP, all things work fine if I using the specific type Handler. The code template must change one Handler to another, but when I check doc of http.Handler, it just a interface, so due to the decouple of project, it will better per module per Handler than change one to another.

Comment: All I need now is the combination of filesystem and http api, might the best way to achieve is that to create another http.Server to serve separately, but it will make a redundant project. I'm a bit confuse.

Comment: @ccd I don't know, this is too vague for me to understand what you're trying to convey. Once you have a *concrete code example* that demonstrates *the actual problem* you're facing, then you can ping me if you want and I'll be more than happy in trying to help you find a solution, but until then, carrying this conversation in this manner just seems wasteful, sorry.

Comment: @mkopriva the first of `(` in line 21 report a `handler(ctx, http.Dir("/path/to/root")) used as value` error.

Comment: @ccd again, I have no idea what you're talking about, the link in the first comment compiles and runs **without** an error. If *you* are seeing an error you must have either copied the code incorrectly, or you've passed in invalid values somewhere.